# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, string, swift

I have a JSON response received from server which contains dictionary elements and one of the elements might be array which will contain values such as ["abc","def","ghi"] and I'm assigning this array to the variable called array as shown in the code below:

```
self.array = infoDictionary["element1"] as! [String]
```

The problem I'm facing is that incase there's null against key "element1" then I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFConstantString' to 'NSArray'

This results in my application getting crashed. How can I save my application from crashing in case if there's "" against "element1"?

Comment: My suggestion: *ban* the usage of `as!` and of force-unwrapping in general of your code. Use safe unwrapping everywhere, catch errors, make `else` clauses for your `if let ...` conditions, etc.

Comment: I have a variable declared outside the block, so I cannot use if let...

Comment: Wrong. You can *always* safely unwrap. :) If you can't use `if let`, then use `guard let` or any other of the many safe-unwrapping techniques. *Learn these techniques. :)*

Comment: The error message says that the value for key `element1` is a `String` rather than an `Array`, it's supposed to be `self.array = infoDictionary["element1"] as! String`

Comment: It could either be string or array, if I write it as self.array = infoDictionary["element1"] as! String then what if it returns array, then app will crash again.

Comment: Then you have to check the type.

Comment: The whole intent of as! is to crash if the conversion fails. So no, there is no way to stop your app from crashing when as! fails, because that's the whole intent of it. Use if let ... as? ... for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that the value for key `element1` is a `String` rather than an `Array`.

If that value could be both `String` and `[String]` you have to check the type:

```
if let item = infoDictionary["element1"] {
   if item is String {
      print("I'm String")
   } else if item is [String] {
      print("I'm Array")
   }
}
```